# How to set limitations for checkbox using ajax and session?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, session

I have never done combining ajax and session before. So far i have done something like this.

```
var sessionvar;
            $.ajaxSetup({cache: false})
            $.get('test.php' ,function (data) {
                sessionvar = data;
                alert(sessionvar);
                var checkedCbs = $('sessionvar:checked');
                if (checkedCbs.length === 4) {
                    alert("You can only select 3 books");
                     this.checked = false;      
                }
            });
```

I want to try set the limitations based on session. Inside the test.php i have something like this

```
<?php

session_start();
if(isset($_POST['sBorrow']) && $_POST['action']){

    if(isset($_SESSION['sBorrow']) && is_array($_SESSION['sBorrow'])){
        $sborrow = $_POST['sBorrow'];
        $set = $_SESSION['sBorrow'];
    }
    else{
        $set = array();
    }

    if($_POST['action'] == "SET"){
        array_push($set, $_POST['sBorrow']);
        $_SESSION['sBorrow'] = $set;    

    }
    else if($_POST['action'] == "UNSET"){
        $unset = $_SESSION['sBorrow'];
        if(($key = array_search($_POST['sBorrow'], $unset)) !== false) {
            unset($unset[$key]);
            $_SESSION['sBorrow'] = $unset;
        }
    }
}
//session_destroy();
if(isset($_SESSION['sBorrow'])){
    $countses = count($_SESSION['sBorrow']);

    echo $countses; 
}
    // nothing requested, so return all values
    print json_encode($_SESSION);
?>
```

Inside these i have create some array to store something. Never mind that, i just want to know how to run an ajax with session. Im not sure if my codes is right for implementing that.

Comment: Define 'limitations'

Comment: for example, i have 10 checkbox. Then by limitations, i mean that im not allowing the user from selecting more than 3 checkbox. Got what i mean?

Comment: .....  the block of code i posted is the thing i have tried. The print display the correct output of an array of the session. However, when i included the code of limitations (cbsChecked and so on...), the limitations not working.

Comment: Simple thing to say, i did succeed on calling the session. its just now i can't use the session to be a part of conditional statement for checkbox limitations

Comment: What does `alert(sessionvar);` popup with? Also: I don't see anything here to do with checkboxes. Perhaps post your HTML code?